# CoreBluetooth and MFi

Tags: ios, mfi, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My company creates hardware accessories that are approved through MFi. With iOS 5, Apple has finally made Bluetooth open to BLE devices without using the ExternalAccessory framework.

I have been unable to find any information on MFi about using CoreBluetooth.

My question is: Can accessories and apps be created using CB but not use the an authentication chip and still be able to have Made for iPod / iPhone / iPad badges?

As far as I can tell the certification process has not changed to accommodate CB-only apps and accessories. Any information is appreciated.

Obviously I'm not expecting people to post MFi information that violates the agreement. I'm simply looking for a general answer and ideally a link or document name to an MFi document that is eluding me.

Comment: Your question is a legal one, not a programming one. Traditionally, SO frowns on those types of questions. Apple would be the one to ask in this case. And, having delt with the MFi people, I know they will get on the phone to speak with you if you need to ask something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an authoritative answer but as far as I know, you can *only* use the badge if Apple has certified your device, which can only happen if you're in the MFi program. Apple will *not* allow you into the MFi program if your device only uses CoreBluetooth. And you can *only* use the authentication chip if you're in MFi.

So I think that no, you cannot use the badge with any arbitrary Bluetooth product. You can only use it with MFi certified products.

Answer (score 5):

CoreBluetooth is only for BTLE. MFI is for Classic Bluetooth apps.